# use peprocessor macros to generate function calls

Tags: c, macros

I have some specific function prototypes

```c
void init_channel_0(void);
void init_channel_1(void);
void init_channel_2(void);
void init_channel_3(void);
void init_channel_4(void);
void init_channel_5(void);
void init_channel_6(void);
void init_channel_7(void);
void init_channel_8(void);
void init_channel_9(void);
```

I would like to call these functions within a loop:

```c
#define CHANNEL_INIT(channel)  init_channel_##(#channel)

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
   INIT_CHANNEL(i)
}
```

I tried to do this using some macro definitions but it didn't work
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Should be `init_channel_##channel##()` IMO, that is, after deciphering your rather cryptic description.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass run-time values to the pre-processor. Use arrays.

```
typedef void channel_func_t (void);

...

channel_func_t*const CHANNEL_INIT [] =
{
  init_channel_0,
  init_channel_1,
  ..
};

...

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
  CHANNEL_INIT[i]();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### A usual approach to do that is to *generate* some C code.

You would write some metaprogram (in C or [Python](https://python.org/) or [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Lua](https://lua.org/) or  [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) or whatever scripting language you like) generating a file `_do_init_channel.inc`  containing

```
 /// generated _do_init_channel.inc
 init_channel_0();
 init_channel_1();
```

etc...

and you would `#include "do_init_channel.inc"`  at the appropriate place.

Of course, adapt your build automation (e.g. your `Makefile`) accordingly.

The [answer by Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64892116/841108) is correct, but if the `init_channel_`<sub>**k**</sub>  functions are tiny and known, an optimizing compiler could inline them easily.

BTW, you could be interested by *existing* C code generators such as [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [SWIG](https://swig.org/) or [RPCGEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN).